# How to pass a react component to another react component, using ReactComponent?

Tags: reactjs

I have a generic button where I want to pass an icon as a component

```
 export const GenericButton = ({ name, type, iconType, text, primary }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={primary ? 'genericButton_primary' : 'genericButton_secondary'}
        name={name}
        type={type}
      >
          <span className='genericButton_icon'>
            {iconType}
          </span>
        {text}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

and here I have a parent in which I pass these components

```
import { ReactComponent as Google } from '../../common/g logo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Fb } from '../../common/f logo.svg';

....

<GenericButton 
   name='gmail'
   type='button'
   text='Register with Google'
   iconType={<Google />}
  />
  <GenericButton 
    name='fb'
    type='button'
    text='Register with Facebook'
    iconType={<Fb />}
  />
```

As a result I get two buttons with the same icon, why?

Comment: I dont see any issues, i tried to reproduce that using sandbox, worked fine for me. Check this here. https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-kepler-10ys0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

```
import { ReactComponent as Google } from '../../common/g logo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Fb } from '../../common/f logo.svg';

....

<GenericButton 
   name='gmail'
   type='button'
   text='Register with Google'
   iconType={Google}
  />
  <GenericButton 
    name='fb'
    type='button'
    text='Register with Facebook'
    iconType={Fb}
  />


 export const GenericButton = ({ name, type, iconType, text, primary }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <button
        className={primary ? 'genericButton_primary' : 'genericButton_secondary'}
        name={name}
        type={type}
      >
          <span className='genericButton_icon'>
            <iconType />
          </span>
        {text}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I copied your code, now the <iconType /> element is empty